# "Unanswered" questions tab shows answered questions

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions, bug-reports

Why does the "Unanswered" tab in the main orange bar produce a result different than "Unanswered" in the "Questions" sub-tab?

Is there a way to make this less ambiguous?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A question isn't answered until it has at least one answer with a score of at least +1.

Comment: Woah, I just realized that confusingly "unanswered" in the "Questions" sub tab produces different results from "unanswered" in the main orange bar.  I'm going to revise the question/ bug report -- +1 thanks.

Comment: Good to know. Doesn't that result in abandoned questions inflating the unanswered question rate?